Why Java interface inner class protected method is accessible from outside?
I have following code:
public interface ISomeInterface {

   class A {
      protected static void protectedMethod() {
         System.out.println("protectedMethod");
      }
      private static void privateMethod() {
         System.out.println("privateMethod");
      }

   }
}

In main, I can call protectedMethod but not privateMethod. Why is that?
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      ISomeInterface.A.protectedMethod(); //okay!
      //ISomeInterface.A.privateMethod(); // Compilation error
   }
}   


Because you're in the same package, presumably.

check Java Language Specification 6.6.2. Details on protected Access -- since you can access the class A with default (package) access, you can also access protected for being in same package

As per documentation:

The protected keyword in Java is an access modifier used for member
variables and methods. It provides a level of access control that
allows access within the same package and by subclasses, even if
they are in different packages.


Read up on this more - I vote for bringing back private protected or something equivalent.
